# Why does kotlin arrow bind throw a kotlin.coroutines.cancellation.CancellationException exception, and only when there's an explicit catch?

Tags: kotlin

I don't understand why using the `bind` function from the [kotlin arrow](https://arrow-kt.io/learn/typed-errors/working-with-typed-errors/) library throws the exception below. Without a try/catch, no exception is thrown. But when you add a try/catch, the exception below is thrown and caught. I've looked through the docs about `bind` and `raise` but can't find an explanation. At the very least it seems like the `CancellationException` is a red herring, as there are no coroutines here.

I'm using the latest version of kotlin arrow, 1.2.3.

```
fun someProcess(): Either<String, Boolean> = either {
    try {
        getStringOrBool().bind()
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        println("Got exception $ex")
        false
    }
}

fun getStringOrBool(): Either<String, Boolean> {
    return "String".left()
}
```

Exception:

```
Got exception arrow.core.raise.NoTrace: kotlin.coroutines.cancellation.CancellationException should never get swallowed. Always re-throw it if captured.This swallows the exception of Arrow's Raise, and leads to unexpected behavior.When working with Arrow prefer Either.catch or arrow.core.raise.catch to automatically rethrow CancellationException.
```

If I modify the code to use arrow's built-in `catch` function, the code works as expected:

```
fun someProcess(): Either<String, Boolean> = either {
    catch({
        getStringOrBool().bind()
    }) {ex: Exception ->
        println("Got exception $ex")
        false
    }
}

fun getStringOrBool(): Either<String, Boolean> {
    return "String".left()
}
```

However, I find the behavior with the `try/catch` unintuitive and error-prone, and I'd like to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Kotlin coroutines’ mechanism for achieving prompt cancellation by throwing CancellationException, Arrow’s Raise does this for short-circuiting a computation. As a Raise uses this to allow something to be cancelled and have that wrapped in the result, swallowing the exception would break its ability to know about its own state and would lead to undefined behaviors. For example, a cancelled computation may not be known to have been cancelled because the CancellationException didn’t get thrown on up to the top level, where Raise internals would catch it and check its type to know what happened.

Comment: As described in the question, there are no coroutines in the provided code. This is why I'd like to understand why arrow throws this exception in this context, which the answer does not address.

Comment: Ah, I see now from browsing the source code of Arrow. The Raise DSL they have built utilizes CancellationExceptions for short-circuiting behavior very similar to how Kotlin coroutines uses them for fast-failing cancelled coroutines.